# Wordpress serving every page and files as homepage

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress install that is a multisite setup and the site has a DNS pointing to it.

Both the site and home URLs have been changed to the domain.

If i visit the site all the javascript and css files are served as the homepage HTML so everything is broken. Also if you click on any link it delivers the homepage and not the requested page.

I have tried changing the theme to twenty seventeen and disabling all the plugins, but the problem persist.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
I moved the site to a subdirectory and changed back to a single site, so now the site is almost a direct clone from its original host, but the problem with every page loading the homepage still persists.

here is the htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdirectory/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Update 2:**
Digging deeper i found that every page has empty query vars which is why its only loading the home page.

```
add_filter('request', 'overwrite_query', 10, 1);
function overwrite_query($q){
  var_dump($query);
}
```

returns 
array(0) {}

Comment: I suspect this is a server-config-level problem, and not a WordPress-level problem. What does your `.htaccess` file look like?

Comment: @CameronHurd its the default multisite htacess

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the htaccess file and trying a new one? I think WP will create one if it doesn't find one.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work, but when i copied over a htaccess from the old host the problem persist

Answer (score 0):

Please open wp-admin page (Wordpress back-end page) then update permalink. then after work perfectly javascript and css.

Comment: The javascript and css files are working now, but every page/post view only pulls the data from the homepage/front page. This happens on the default theme with no plugins activated